# Normalize and compress video audio

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-promotion

The audio on the Avengers vs. X-Men promotion videos seems incredibly quiet.  Can you normalize and/or compress the audio tracks in the future?

e.g.:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aqXpjy1FOs

Comment: Ronan over at Gaming.SE [seems willing to produce your videos](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4235317#4235317).

Comment: @BrettWhite make answer so I can tick it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did not seem quiet when I was editing them, but I was also under a crazy deadline to get them all finished. This will be corrected in the future.